# Discord - How to handle connection lost error?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to handle the following error with `try` in `discord.py`, it happens whenever my bot loses connection.

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
...
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
...
raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host discord.com:443 ssl:default [Temporary failure in name resolution]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Useful Links

- [`aiohttp.ClientConnectorError`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientConnectorError)
- [Handling Errors and Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

---

You have not provided the code you have currently, so I'm guessing what you have, try to include what all you have in your question always.

### Example

you can do it as follows

```py
import aiohttp
...

@client.event
async def on_message():
    ...
    try:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
    except aiohttp.ClientConnectorError:
        ...
```

and the error is handled here.

Comment: I don't have any `for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):` in my script, my code is just `on_message` and `process commands`

Comment: fixed, check the answer again.

Comment: Okay, I’ll try this and update you later